# Is there any maximum for number of vertices of a k-tree?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any upper-bound for number of vertices we can  add to a *k-tree* with $k+1$ vertices so that the resulting graph be also a *k-tree*?

We now each new vertex can connect only with $k$ vertex of available vertices. I think there is no upper-bound. because in each step we can use latest added vertex and $k-2$ vertex of it's neighbors and one vertex that latest added vertex is not connected to that vertex. Is my intuition right?